# Given a positive-definite integral unimodular Gram matrix, how to find a basis of the associated lattice (over $\mathbf Q$)?

Tags: lattices, quadratic-forms, euclidean-lattices

Let $G$ be a $n\times n-$symmetric matrix with *integral coefficients* and determinant $1$ (*i.e. unimodular*) such that the associated quadratic form is positive-definite.

I am interested in having an algorithm to find a *rational* basis of a lattice $L$ such that $G$ is the Gram matrix of $L$. Concretely, this consists in finding a *square* matrix $M$ (with rational coefficients) such that $G$ factors as $^tM \cdot M$.

Note that:

1) The unimodular condition and Hasse-Minkowski theory predict that this is indeed possible (this is a remark in Serre's course in arithmetics, §1.3.6 p. 86 in the French edition).

2) I demand the matrix $M$ to be square. (For non-square $M$, this is much easier: first by the Gram-Schmidt process, one can assume that $M$ is diagonal (with positive rational entries); then write each diagonal entry as a sums of  (at most 4) squares).

Comment: If you do "completing squares" on the quadratic form      $f(x)=x^TGx$, you can rewrite it as 
$x^TGx=\sum D_j(x_j+a_{j,j+1}x_{j+1}+...+a_{j,n}x_n)^2$
where all the coefficients are rationals. This is equivalent to the expression $G=M_1^tDM_1$ where $D$ is diagonal and $M_1$ is triangular. So $M=\sqrt{D}M_1$ but this is not rational because of the square root.

Comment: Yes, that's more or less implicit in my "note n°2".

Comment: Yes. Now I understand what you mean : Gram Schmidt is essentially completing squares but how to write 1/7 as a sum of squares of rationals ?

Comment: 1/7=7/49 and 7=2²+1²+1²+1², so 1/7=(2/7)²+(1/7)^2+(1/7)^2+(1/7)^2.

Comment: In general, p/q=pq/q^2 and use Lagrange's theorem to decompose a the (positive) numerator as a sum of at most 4 squares.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a method.

Let $\mathrm{V}$ be the bilinear space $(\mathbf Q^n, b)$ with Gram Matrix $G$ in the canonical basis.

Let $M_0$ be the lattice $\mathbf Z^n$ on $\mathbf Q^n$. Find a primitive vector $v_0\in M_0$ such that $b(v_0,v_0)$ is a square, say $b(v_0,v_0)=m^2$ in $M_0$ (note that this can be done quite efficiently : use LLL to get a basis of vectors with small norms, take the two* first vectors, study the lattice they generate).

( * **Edit 1:** in fact you need to take the first 4 vectors ... indeed, there exists (many) $3\times 3$ positive definite Gram matrices that don't represent any square over $\mathbf Q$ ... The simplest example is $7.I_3$.)

( **Edit 2:** If you don't use this trick, you can arrange so as to find a $v_0$ such that $m=2^s$ ... this will allow you to find an orthonormal basis inside $\mathbf Z[\frac 12]^n$, whose existence is predicted by the Strong Approximation Theorem.)

Let $K_1$ be the lattice made of vectors $w\in M_0$ such that $(v,w)\equiv 0$ mod. $m$.

Let $L_1$ be the lattice $K_1+\mathbf Z\cdot\frac{v_0}{m}$. Then $L_1$ is integral, unimodular, and has a vector of length $1$, namely $w_0:=\frac{v_0}{m}$.

Let $M_1$ be the orthogonal complement of $w_0$ in $L_1$. Then $M_1$ is an $n-1$-dimensional unimodular lattice (contained in the $n-1$-dimensional subspace $<w_0>^\perp$ of $\mathrm{V}$).

Go on to find $v_1\in M_1$, construct $M_2$ and so on ... you're done (the matrix $M$ you were looking for is the inverse of the matrix whose columns are $(w_0,\dots,w_{n-1})$.

[The classification of unimodular lattices shows that at least when $n\leq 7$, you can always arrange so as to have $(v_0,v_0)=1$ (so that $M_1\subset M_0$), and for $n\leq 24$, you can find some $v_0$ with $(v_0,v_0)=4$.]

Comment: @Oblomov : I would not like to seem fidgety but ... after one week, what do you think of this answer ? (ok, you had to wait 2 month before getting an answer to your question, so maybe I should expect it will also ask you two month to comment on it ...)

Comment: Indeed, sorry for my delay in reading your answer.

Comment: I am a bit confused by the first step. My (stupid) question is: why does a positive definite 4-dimensional integral quadratic form represent a square?

Comment: Ok, I know why it represents a square, but is there an algorithmic way to find such a vector?

Comment: Yes, even if it is not necessarily efficient : identify successively the spheres of square radii 1,4,9, etc. There are algorithms to do this.

Comment: @Oblomov : I can write you a magma function that does the full job if you need it.